# why is my async code inside for loop not running sequentially?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why do all my function calls get executed in parallel here when using await? What needs to be changed in order to start a function call once the previous is done?

```js
    for (let collection of collections) {
      await this.updateListings(collection)
    }
```

```js
  private async updateListings(collection: Collection) {

    try {

      const startTime = Date.now();
      const supply = collection.stats.total_supply;
      const contract_address = collection.primary_asset_contracts[0].address;
      const token_ids = [];

      for (let i = 1; i <= supply; i++) {
        token_ids.push(i);
      }

      let offset = 0;
      let limit = 30;

      while (offset + limit <= supply) {

        this.apiKey = this.apiKeys.find(key => key !== this.apiKey);    //rotate api key on each request

        const ids = token_ids.splice(0, 30);
        const params = new URLSearchParams();
        params.set("offset", offset.toString());
        params.set("limit", limit.toString());
        params.set("side", "1");
        params.set("sale_kind", "0");
        params.set("order_by", "eth_price");
        params.set("order_direction", "asc");
        params.set("asset_contract_address", contract_address);

        for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
          params.append("token_ids", ids[i])
        }

        await this.delayRequest(700);
        const response = await axios.get(process.env.OPENSEA_API_BASE_URL + "/orders", {
          headers: {
            "X-API-KEY": this.apiKey,
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'
          },
          params: params
        })
        const { orders } = response.data;

        if (orders.length > 0) await getRepository(Listing).save(orders);

        offset += limit;
        console.log(`update listings for ${collection.slug} status: ${offset} / ${supply}`)
      }

      const endTime = Date.now() - startTime;
      console.log("fetched listings for " + collection.slug + " in " + endTime + " ms")
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("updating listings for " + collection.slug + " failed", error.message);
    }

  }
```

```js
  constructor() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.update();
    }, 6000)
  }
```

What I expect is that the first iteration finishes before it proceeds but its calling each iteration "updateListings(coll)" at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

In fact. your code is executed sequentially. How did you check that your code was running in parallel?

You can use Array.reduce to make it sequentially:

```
return collections.reduce((currentPromiseChain, collection) => {
    return currentPromiseChain.then(() => this.updateListings(collection));
}, Promise.resolve());
```

Comment: because inside my updateListings functions I have a log that prints to console when its started and I get all iterations at once logged even though one full process of"updateListings" takes several minutes and I am getting rate limited due to too many requests

Comment: Could you check your NETWORK tab? if 1st `updateListings` is done, it will go to the next one or when submitted, we will have 5 `updateListings` requests in parallel?

Comment: I updated my code maybe yall find an error in there I cant find. The updateListings functions gets called almost simoultaniously for all iterations

Answer (score 0):

Just add an await before the condition. This will ensure each loop finishes before continuing to the next one.

Note: not fully sure on the compatibility for this, you may need check for compatibility.

```js
for await (let collection of collections) { //notice the await in this line.
    await this.updateListings(collection)
}
```

Comment: tried that did not make any difference. Updated original post

Answer (score 0):

This is to demostrate there isn't anything wrong with the way you are calling `for loop`, and also how you have a `while loop` inside your `updateListing` function.

There's probably something you didn't show?

The only reason I can see, affecting your codes, is if there are errors, and your try/catch block returns the promise with error immediately, making it appears it is running in parallel.

```js
const whileLoopFunction = async(value) => {

    let limit = 0;
    let supply = 10

    while (limit < supply) {

       await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve,100))
       limit++
    }
    console.log('While loop complete for value ', value)

};

(async() => {

const collections = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

console.log("For loop works with await")
for (let collection of collections) {
    await whileLoopFunction(collection)
}




})()
```

Comment: I updated my post so everything used is showing. I still dont understand why it is executed in parallel. I have a console.log at the beginning of updateListings now, when I run the app somewhere in the middle of the first updateListings() call I get a log from the next iteration already even tho the first one is still running in the while loop.

Comment: can u show the log

Comment: And how is this `for loop` called? Is it in another loop? is it triggered by something else, and end up getting triggered several times?

Comment: added it to original post

Comment: did you call the class multiple times? You can try to debug by leaving only the axios call in your code to see if it's called multiple times. As demostrated, there's nothing wrong with the loop call. It's either the loop called multiple times or something else beyond these codes called the function multiple times, which is hard for us to debug on your behalf...